# コマンドプロントのsortの書き換え方法

Tags: windows, sort

Windowsでの作業で困ってます。

DOSコマンドの[`sort`](http://itpro.nikkeibp.co.jp/free/NT/WinKeyWord/20040805/1/sort.shtml)をコマンドプロンプトで使い、ファイルの中身をソートして上書き保存したいのですが、方法が分かりません。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　この質問ですが、情報が少なく、中西さんが何をしていてどこで困っているのかが殆ど分かりません。何かプログラミングをしているのであればどういう言語を使っているのかが書いてあるべきです。また、コーディングしていてお困りなら、その動かないコードを書き加えてください。質問の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、お願いします。ヘルプセンターの[「良い質問をするには?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) もご覧ください。

Comment: もしかして、DOSコマンドの[`sort`](http://itpro.nikkeibp.co.jp/free/NT/WinKeyWord/20040805/1/sort.shtml)を使ってファイルの内容をソートし、しかもその結果を元のファイルに反映したいということでしょうか？

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、正にその通りです。

Comment: 具体的にどういうコマンドを使ってみたら上手くいかなかったという例はありますか？

Comment: ファイルの内容のサンプルと期待する実行結果の例を加えて下さい。 コマンドの使い方は`sort /?`でヘルプが表示されます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort input.txt /o output.txt`
こゆことです？
`input.txt`がsort対象で、`output.txt`が結果出力が保存されるfileです。
入力と出力を同じfile名にしたら上書きされますよ。